# If value of (#formID) is greater than 100000 show this Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, show-hide

How can I make a div show or hide based on a form inputs value.  Specifically if It's value is positive.  I want it to show one div.  Otherwise I want it to show another div.

Here is the more complex thing that I actually want 
. If form1 is greater than 10,000 and form2 is less than zero. Show this first div(if both are met). If condition for form 1 is met and form two is not met(form 2 is a positive number) show this second div.If anything else(neither are met or form 1 not met(9000) but form two is(a negative number) show this third div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume you have the following to divs:

```
   <div class="show_when_more">
     Foo 
  </div>

   <div class="show_when_less">
     Bar
   </div>
```

And the following input you want to be watching:

```
   <input type="text" class="to_watch"/>
```

Then the following Javascript would do it for you (you would require jquery for this to work):

```
   $('input.to_watch').on('change', function(){
       if($(this).val()>=1000){
           $('div.show_when_more').css('display', 'block');
           $('div.show_when_less').css('display', 'none');
       } else {
           $('div.show_when_more').css('display', 'none');
           $('div.show_when_less').css('display', 'block');
       }
    });
```

This would also work with any other type of selector (eg by id, by element type, etc)

Comment: Awesome. You are a life saver. I owe you. What would I do if I wanted it to look at two conditions. This was my attempt. But I'm not very good obviously. It has errors, http://jsfiddle.net/7aNwP/15/

Comment: And what are you expecting that jsfiddle to do exactly?

Comment: HAha nothing now.  because I don't know js. I stick to html and css.  But I want it to see if form 1 is greater than 10000, AND form 2 is greater than zero.  And then the function is the same. But I want to set two conditions

Comment: Could you give a somewhat more detailed example of what you mean when you say "two conditions"?

Comment: Ya! Thanks! here it is exactly. If form1 is greater than 10,000 and form2 is less than zero. Show this first div(if both are met). If condition for form 1 is met and form two is not met(form 2 is a positive number) show this second div.If anything else(neither are met or form 1 not met(9000) but form two is(a negative number) show this third div

Comment: You could put an onchange event on the field in both forms, then from within the first onchange do a jquery selector for the second and vice versa, checking both conditions that way.

Answer (score 0):

here is the logic. just apply to your project.

```
var value = document.getElementById('input').value;

if(value === 1000) {
//show the first div
}
else {
//show the second div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to see if it is positive you can check to see if it is >= 0 (or 1, depending on what you are going for).

when doing checks on numbers it is a good idea to parseint() on it first.

Throw it in an if statement:

```
if (value >= 0) { then show one div } else { show a different div }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like below:

```
$(function() {
  if(isNaN(parseInt($("#in").val())))
  { 
   $("#divtobeshown").show();
  }
  else {
     $("#divtobehidden").hide();
  }
});


<form id="sform">
  <input value="" id="in" >
</form>
```

A simple illustration on [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7aNwP/15/)